# Load a Laravel blade without refreshing the page

Tags: jquery, laravel

I'm currently working on a task by categorizing 3 matches;
**(ALL)(DOTA2)(CSGO)(NBA)**

Assume that I have the blade files `home.blade.php`, `dota2.blade.php`, `csgo.blade.php` and `nba.blade.php`, and this is the container:

```
<div class="m-container2" id="right">
   <div id="matchesHolder" class="main-ct">
      <div class="title">MATCHES </div>
      <div class="matchmain">
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I did the latest load content jquery I've seen but none of it works well. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: You need ajax dude

Comment: @CamiloGoJr. yeah I know, that's why I asked for help cause the ajax jquery that I've tried didn't work.

Comment: We can't help if the code is not posted.

Comment: Post your code. Basically you should have a method some where (probably in one of your controllers) that will response to ajax call.